Understanding the phrase halacha l'Moshe mi'Sinai
I am trying to understand the phraseology of the term halacha l'Moshe mi'Sinai, specifically why the word Sinai is used, rather than Hashem. There are certain sages who hold that not every part of the Oral Law was given at Sinai (some were given in the Plains of Moab) so I assume that (at least according to these opinions) the word Sinai is used colloquially to really mean any time after the Exodus and before Moses died.
Furthermore, using the phrase halacha l'Moshe m'Hashem would seem to me to be more accurate, and forcefully underlining that the Oral Law was equally transmitted by God to Moshe.
Do any commentaries explain the phrase halacha l'Moshe mi'Sinai and specifically the emphasis on Sinai as opposed to Hashem?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100011/why-is-god-not-mentioned-in-the-opening-line-of-pirkei-avot

@MauriceMizrahi I hope very much so

There is a really detailed analysis on pp. 32-41 in the book "The Path of Torah" by Netziv. There is a closely related term gemiri.

I saw a pirush on Mishna Avot 1:1 that says the torah is already given on Sinai to mankind, and heavenly bodies doesn't have the permission to argue on the chachamim who are worldly. May be we can connect these

Here is how Hakham José Faur explained it in the Horizontal Society:



